# Add/Inject/Force <meta-data> line into manifest of every installed app

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-source, xposed

the problem is, i use OP5T, and none of any 8.0/8.1 stock custom rom does support 18:9 scaling feature like in OOS, this feature named as "Full Screen Apps" under app category.

after a few googling, i came up with these method:

1.) add/inject/force this into manifest file of every installed app. or maybe doing some workaround with the packagemanager

> meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1"

2.) playing inside AOSP source code, parsePackage method.

> frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java.

i know nothing of creating xposed module, but before starting my journey, is it possible to do the first method with xposed?

after seeing module like Xinstaller, App Settings, and XAspect. i thought it may be possible with xposed to approach this.
really appreciate every kind of help, thanks before

Comment: If you ever managed to build this xposed module, I'd be glad to give it a try, I'm struggling to get a way to force apps to scale to 18:9 on my op5t :)

Answer (score 1):

Xposed Framework can do this!

Xposed cannot edit manifest xml files directly, but it can indeed do the way 2.) you proposed:

Xposed Framework can "hook" any method to execute arbitray code before/after/replace that method. You are indeed on the right track, and `PackageParser.java` seems like the right class : I'm not so sure about the `parsePackage()` method though - a glance at AOSP seems to suggest that perhaps the method `parseMetaData()` might be a better candidate to hook?

Some background on Xposed -

You will need Java to create any Xposed modules. Android itself is based on (primarily) Java, so you will need Java knowledge to make Xposed modules.

As for Tutorials, Rovo89 (the creator of Xposed) has a simple tutorial here at https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial. This tutorial is almost completely upto-date, and you can use this to create your first module.

You will find another detailed tutorial here - https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2709324. Keep in mind that this link is very old, so wherever there are any conflicts, go by Rovo89's tutorial.